# Is every locally connected subset of Euclidean space R^n locally path connected ?

Tags: gn.general-topology

This is not actually a question asked by me. But since I do not know the answer, I would love to know if someone here could answer it.

Comment: This is an interesting question to which I do not know the answer either. I am interested to see the responses though.

Comment: By "subspace", I expect that you mean "subset". I edit you title accordingly.

Comment: What's wrong with subspace? A subspace means a subset with the subspace topology it inherits from the ambient space. 

Comment: Some people might misread as "vector subspace".

Comment: That would be a very strange misreading! 

Comment: I've searched through all the reference tables in Counterexamples in Topology. I didn't see any answers to the question. 


Comment: Instead of subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ one can talk, equivalently, about finite-dimensional separable metric spaces. Infinite-dimensional examples are of interest too.

Comment: A misreading that sound strange for a certain community and/or in a certain context would be unavoidable in another one. Certainly here I view "subset" as clearer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. There are locally connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are totally path disconnected. See my answer to this old MO question "[Can you explicitly write R<sup>2</sup> as a disjoint union of two totally path disconnected sets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156/can-you-explicitly-write-r2-as-a-disjoint-union-of-two-totally-path-disconnected)". Also, Gerald Edgar's response to the same question says that such sets cannot be totally disconnected, although he does not mention local connectedness. In fact, the sets given by my answer are locally connected, so provide a counterexample to your question.

As in the linked question: Let $S$ be a subset of the reals such that $S\cap[a,b]$ and $S^{\rm c}\cap[a,b]$ cannot be written as a countable union of closed sets for any $a < b$ (e.g., this [explicit example of a non-Borel set](https://planetmath.org/alebesguemeasurablebutnonborelset)). Then, $A=(S\times\mathbb{Q})\cup(S^{\rm c}\times\mathbb{Q}^{\rm c})$ and $B=(S\times\mathbb{Q}^{\rm c})\cup(S^{\rm c}\times\mathbb{Q})$ partition the plane into a pair of locally connected and totally pathwise disconnected sets.

That they are totally pathwise disconnected is proven in my answer to the linked question. Let us show that $A\cap U$ is connected for any nonempty 'open rectangle' $U=(x_0,x_1)\times(y_0,y_1)$. If not, there would be nonempty disjoint open sets $V,W\subset U$ with $A\cap(V\cup W)=A\cap U$. If $\pi(x,y)=x$ is the projection onto the *x*-axis then $\pi(V)\cup\pi(W)=\pi(V\cup W)=(x_0,x_1)$ is connected. So, we can find a nontrivial closed interval $[a,b]\subseteq\pi(V)\cap\pi(W)$.
Now, for every $x\in S^{\rm c}\cap[a,b]$, the line segment $\lbrace x\rbrace\times(y_0,y_1)$ intersects with both $V$ and $W$ and, by connectedness of line segments, it will intersect with $U\setminus(V\cup W)$. Hence, there is a $q\in\mathbb{R}$ with $(x,q)\in U\setminus(V\cup W)\subset B$. So, $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. For each rational $q$, let $S_q$ be the (closed) set of $x\in[a,b]$ such that $(x,q)$ is in $U\setminus(V\cup W)$.
Then, $S^{\rm c}\cap[a,b]=\bigcup_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}S_q$  is a countable union of closed sets, giving the required contradiction. Hence $A$ is locally connected and, exchanging $S$ and $S^{\rm c}$ in the argument above, so is $B$.

Comment: Great answer!  But I think it would be easier to read if you used TeX instead of HTML for the math.  For one thing, having variable names appear in italics helps a lot.

Comment: Ok, since you ask, I'll change it to use latex. In the early days of MO, latex support was not so good, so I got into the habit of using html (and for long answers, latex can still be cumbersome, but that doesn't apply here).

Comment: Wow, very impressive! 

Answer (score 4):

Isn't every connected subset of ${\mathbb R}^n$ locally a  [Peano space?](https://planetmath.org/PeanoSpace)  Then the answer would be "yes".

**Edit**  I assumed the subspace to be closed. Then it would be locally compact, hence locally Peano. I guess the main difficulty is for not closed subsets.

Comment: What about compactness?

Comment: It is not in general, since a Peano space is compact, by definition.

Comment: I found a proof of the fact that a Peano space is arcwise connected at http://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&lpg=PA221&ots=TQpbClZELw&dq=peano%20space%20arcwise%20connected&pg=PA219#v=onepage&q=peano%20space%20arcwise%20connected&f=false

Answer (score 4):

An easy counterexample:
The basic space that is connected but not locally connected is the closure of the graph $y=\sin(1/x)$ ("the topologist sine curve").
Call it $S$. Pick a countable set $D$ on the graph $y=\sin(1/x)$ whose closure is $D\cup \{0\}\times [-1,1]$. For each point $z \in D$ add a copy $S_z$ of $S$ (in $R^3$) starting from $z$ and ending on an interval in $0 \times [-1,1]$ so that the diameter of $S_z$ is at most twice the distance from $z$ to the  $y$-axis and $S_z$ intersects $S_w$ only along the $y$-axis if $z$ is different from $w$. The union $C$ of $S$ and all $S_z$, $z \in D$, is clearly locally connected.
Any arc from $w$ in $D$ to the $y$-axis contained in $C$ would have to be contained in $S$ (it intersects each $S_z$ at most in $z$), a contradiction.

Added after reading comments:
Let's pick a sequence of planes $\Pi_n$ containing the $y$-axis and converging from above (from the point of view of the half-plane $x\ge 0$) to the $xy$-plane where $S$ resides. Enumerate points $z\in D$ as $z_n$, $n\ge 1$.
From each $z_n$ go up until you hit $\Pi_n$ and then create a scaled copy of $S$ lying on $\Pi_n$ and ending on the $y$-axis.
That should guarantee $S_z\cap S_w \subset y-\text{axis}$.

Why is $C$ locally connected?
The issue is only with point on the $y$-axis. Given any $\epsilon > 0$ and $-1\leq y\leq 1$, consider the union of all $S_z$ that intersect $0\times [y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon]\times 0$ and are of diameter less that $\epsilon$. Add $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of end-points of $S_z$s in $S$. That set is connected, of small diameter, and it contains $(0,y,0)$ in its interior rel.C.

Comment: It's hard for me to see how you keep $S_z$ and $S_w$ from intersecting outside the $y$-axis.  If it is convenient to include a picture, that would be a big help...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by a copy $S_z$ of $S$ in $R^3$?

Comment: I assume that the idea is to scale and translate S to join z to the y-axis, then bend it a bit in the third dimension to avoid intersections. I don't know why this results in a "clearly locally connected" set though.

Comment: Jurek, your example almost made me think I understand the problem, but... I don't think $C$ is locally connected at all points of the graph $G\subset S$ of $\sin\frac1x$. Let $p\in G$, and let $p_n$ be a sequence of distinct points in $D$ converging to $p$. Then $S_{p_n}$ Hasdorff-converge to a scaled copy $h(S)$ of $S$ lying in the horizontal plane. Its intersection with $S$ surely contains a $q\in G$ that is far from $p$ and from the $y$ axis. Now $q=h(r)$ for some $r\in G$, and the images $r_n$ of $r$ in $S_{p_n}$ converge to $q$. Any small connected sets containing almost all of the $r_n$?

Comment: There is an interesting example here http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1942-48-02/S0002-9904-1942-07615-4
(see Property 7). 

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier.
The problem is that I want the boundary of $D$ to be the edge of $0\times [-1,1]$ of the sine curve, not to be dense in all of it.

Comment: OK, now I see. You probably want a bit more than that, because you don't want $D$ to be concentrated, say, only in increasing intervals of the graph and miss the decreasing ones. But this is easy to arrange. So the problem finally makes sense to me! I wonder if your technique applies also to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25171 ?

Comment: Old topic, but let me point out that C is compact hence cannot be locally connected without being path connected according to Vít Tuček's answer. In fact, the example C (which is nice once you understand the description) is not locally connected. It comes from the part of the first few $S_z$ that is close to $y\in$ the y-axis.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer is that this is true for compact sets (as stated in the answer by Mark Sapir) and also for all open sets  $M$, because one can prove rather easily, that the set of all points of $M$ which can be joined to some fixed $x_0\in M$ is open and closed at the same time.

Comment: Easier than that: an open set is always locally path connected, because it contains balls centered at every point.

Comment: Of course. I should think at least three times before I post an answer. I was thinking about nonlocal case, i.e. every open connected subset is path connected.